# Moonmail/Serverless: "s-variables-<stage>-<region>" location?

Tags: serverless-framework, moonmail

I'm looking to install Moonmail. One early step of installing Moonmail is:

> Add variables to s-variables-< stage >-< region >:
>
> ```
> {
>     ...,
>     "apiHost": "yourendpointhost.com"
> }
> ```

I can't find the relevant file to enter this information. Where exactly do I enter this?

The files created by serverless in my Moonmail location are:
s-project.json, s-resources-cf.json, and s-templates.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is inside a new folder created when you ran `sls project init -c -n your-lower-case-project-name`. For example, if you stage is dev and your region is us-east-1, you should see this file:

```
_meta/variables/s-variables-dev-useast1.json
```

Answer (score 1):

`apiHost` is the URL that points to your API Gateway, so you've got to set it after deploying, at least, one endpoint